# How to scroll Imageview with StickyListHeadersListView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scrollview

I want to scroll image with StickyListHeadersListView. My Code like

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_banner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_title_bg"
    android:background="@drawable/banner_img" />

<com.abc.StickyListHeadersListView
    xmlns:slh="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rel_footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_title_bg"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    slh:areHeadersSticky="true" 
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Library on a git_hub
you just have to import it in your eclipse as a project and add to your project as a library

```
https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders
```

This gonna be a good knowledge for you to use external libraries. Have luck.

Comment: I used that one but I want to scroll top image with scrolling listview.for example,suppose I scroll listview it will scroll with his top image like that.